# Is there any possibility to use CodeDeploy environment variables in section files of AppSpec file

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, bitbucket, web-deployment, aws-code-deploy

I have website, which stored on AWS EC2 servers.

We have 2 servers, one for production environment and another one for development and staging environments.

Development and staging environments located in different folders. For example development env stored in `/var/www/development`, while staging stored in `/var/www/staging`.

I'd like to use AWS CodeDeploy to upload files directly from bitbucket. I put AppSpec file, which copy source code to `/var/www/html` folder and install all dependencies and configurations. But I want my AppSpec file to copy source code to `/var/www/development` or to `/var/www/staging` depending on Development group, that was selected.

Is there is any way to do it or, maybe, there are some better approach in my situation?

Comment: Add a tag for both instances, for ex: production server will have tag `env`:`prod` and staging server will have `env`:`stage`. In your appspec hooks first get this tag first and then decide where to copy your archive.

Comment: @levchuk-ivan did you ever get this working? I'm in a similar situation at the moment. Thanks

Comment: @flopperJ, yes, but I don't like the solution. By default application release copy to one folder and after deploy script move source code to the folder according to the deployment group name

Answer (score 7):

The `appspec.yml` is a bit inflexible so use the following to deploy code in to different folders on the same instance.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/my-temp-dir
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/my-temp-dir
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: ci/integrations-deploy-pre.sh
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: ci/integrations-deploy-post.sh
      runas: root
```

Inside of my `integrations-deploy-post.sh` file, I then use the CodeDeploy environment variables to move the files in to the place I need them to be;

```
#!/bin/bash
    
if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "Staging" ]
then
    cp -R /var/www/my-temp-dir /var/www/my-staging-dir
    chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/my-staging-dir

    # Insert other commands that need to run...
fi

if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "UAT" ]
then
    cp -R /var/www/my-temp-dir /var/www/my-uat-dir
    chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/my-uat-dir

    # Insert other commands that need to run...
fi
```

NOTE: In my `integrations-deploy-post.sh` You'll also need the commands you want to run on production. Removed for simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way to change AppSpec or custom scripts behavior is to utilize [environment variables provided by the CodeDeploy agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#reference-appspec-file-structure-environment-variable-availability). You have access to the deployment group name and the application name.

```
if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "Staging" ]; then
  # Copy to /var/www/staging
elif [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "Development" ]; then
  # Copy to /var/www/development
elif [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "Production" ]; then
  # Copy to /var/www/html
else
  # Fail the deployment
fi
```

Comment: So I'm not able use sections `files` of appspec file, I should copy all files myself?

Comment: Hi @EmptyArsenal, Idea is working but syntax is wrong there should be fi not end

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I used source control as a solution to this. 
My workflow is using Gitlab CI > AWS Code Pipeline (S3 Source and CodeDeploy).

So in my development branch, my AppSpec file would look like this:-

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/my-project-dev
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 400
      runas: root
```

in my staging branch:-

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/my-project-staging
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 400
      runas: root
```

---

My Gitlab-CI just uses a shell executor to my EC2 instance and it basically compresses my project folder and uploads to S3.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - deploy
setup dependencies:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - echo "Setup Dependencies"
    - pip install awscli
deploy to s3:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - tar -cvzf /tmp/artifact_$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.tar ./*
    - echo "Copy artifact to S3"
    - aws s3 cp /tmp/artifact_$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.tar s3://project-artifacts/

clean up:
  stage: .post
  script:
    - echo "Removing generated artifact"
    - rm /tmp/artifact_$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.tar
```

Note that `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is used to differentiate the artifact file being generated. In development branch it would be `artifact_development.tar`, in staging  branch `artifact_staging.tar`.

Then, I have 2 pipelines listening to the two respective artifacts which deploys to 2 different CodeDeploy Application.

Not sure if this is the best way, surely welcome any suggestions that is better